# How do I compile a file include linux headers

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, header-files, wsl-2

I've tried to compile this code:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>

int init_module(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World");
    return (0);
}
```

With the following Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.c

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Then it shows me this error message:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build=/home/vers modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build=/home/vers: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

I'm trying to compile linux kernel to my Debian WSL2. I've tried executing `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` but it still failed.

edit: I install Ubuntu 20.04 follow this `https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594470/wsl-2-does-not-have-lib-modules` and It's give me new error

```
make -C /home/vers/gcc/WSL2-Linux-Kernel M=/home/vers/gcc modules
make[1]: *** /home/vers/gcc/WSL2-Linux-Kernel: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

Comment: `-C` tries to change directory before continuing to build the supplied target. Do you really have a directory named `/lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build=/home/vers` ? The error message suggests that you don't.

Comment: When building on a system where you have previously built the kernel, `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build` is a link to the kernel source directory.  That's what you need to put after `-C`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes I don't have one, what do I do now

Comment: @stark okay but in /lib/modules/ only have "6.1.0-11-amd64" file

Comment: You don't need to have anything in /lib/modules.  You need to give the path to your kernel source in the Makefile.

Comment: Hi I install Ubuntu 20.04 and finally compile the WSL2-Linux-Kernel and It's give me the new error
make -C /home/vers/gcc/WSL2-Linux-Kernel M=/home/vers/gcc modules
make[1]: *** /home/vers/gcc/WSL2-Linux-Kernel: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2

Comment: Your `obj-m` line is simply wrong, you. need to have `obj-m += hello-1.o`. See the difference? Yes, you still have to fix the issue with the missing `M=$(PWD)` in the `all` rule.

Answer (score 0):

You copied some information incorrectly.

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build=$(PWD) modules
```

Should be

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

like you have for the `clean` rule.

Comment: It;s still give me the same error

Comment: @SennaThongthao5, see my comment to your question.

Comment: now it give me


make -C /lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build M=/home/vers/gcc modules
  CC [M]  /home/vers/gcc/hello-1.o
/home/vers/gcc/hello-1.o: warning: objtool: init_module(): not an indirect call target
/home/vers/gcc/hello-1.o: warning: objtool: cleanup_module(): not an indirect call target
  MODPOST /home/vers/gcc/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/vers/gcc/hello-1.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:136: /home/vers/gcc/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1984: modpost] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2

Comment: @SennaThongthao5 Does the `/lib/modules/5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2/build` symlink point to the build directory for the kernel you built? And is WSL2 running the kernel you built? I would suggest using a different local version tag in the kernel configuration to avoid confusing your kernel build from Microsoft's kernel build.